# import HTML.App as Html

Tags: elm

The elm tutorial at http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/user_input/buttons.html has these lines:

```
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.App as Html
```

I do not understand what the name `Html` references as the result of these imports. Is it `Html.App` or the function from `Html` package? And why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Html exposing (Html)
```

exposes the identifier `Html` in two different *namespaces*.

1. The Html coming from the brackets part is a type. It's *qualified* name is `Html.Html` and it can only appear in Type signatures.
2. The Html module which can only appear as a qualifier. Hence you could write `Html.img` and this refers to the part immediately after the `import` keyword.

Finally,

```
import Html.App as Html
```

imports the `Html.App` module and also gives it a local alias of `Html`. These don't shadow each other but as long as the actual function names are different in each module the compiler will resolve these correctly for you.

---

I generally avoid aliasing to the same thing since it makes the code confusing for me. But the compiler deals with it no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my understanding...

- if `Html` is used alone then it refers to a type defined
  inside of `Html` module, and it can be used alone because
  it is exposed by `import` directive.
  (i.e. `Html.Html`)
- `Html.xx` (`xx` is arbitrary, whichever `Html.App` module exposes)
  is `xx` exposed by module `Html.App`  (i.e. `Html.App.xx`).
  And it cannot be used alone, because it is not imported with
  name spacing with a word `Html`.

Note that, a period `.` can only be name-spacing operator if 
the left-side word starts with a capital letter.
And, only value (has to starts with a lower-case letter) can have properties, where `.` can also be used.
(`ModuleName.TypeName` vs `recordValue.property`)
So, it is not ambiguous.

But, if two modules expose same name
(e.g. `Html.xx` and `Html.App.xx`)
, then `xx` can become ambiguous
and compiler would complain.

for example, when `Html` modules is imported with `exposing (..)`

I hope it makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

If there is just `Html`, it's the type (originally `Html.Html`).

But if there's `.` after it, it's a module name and you can take definitions from both `Html` and `Html.App` modules by doing `Html.something`.

---

**More in detail:**

The result of `import Html` is that you can access `Html.whateverHtmlExposes`.

The result of the `exposing (Html, button, div, text)` is that you can write

- `Html` instead of `Html.Html` (the type),
- `button` instead of `Html.button` (function),
- etc.

The result of `import Html.App` would be that you can access `Html.App.whateverHtmlAppExposes`, **BUT** because of the `as Html` part you can now write it like `Html.whateverHtmlAppExposes`.

Don't worry about conflicts - the compiler will warn you in that case:

```
-- NAMING ERROR ---------------------------------------------------------- C.elm

This usage of variable `A.x` is ambiguous.

9|     Html.text A.x
                 ^^^
Maybe you want one of the following?

    A.x
    B.x

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

Here I have imported `B` as `A`, both modules have `x` exposed:

A.elm

```
module A exposing (x)
x = "x from A"
```

B.elm

```
module B exposing (x)
x = "x from B"
```

C.elm

```
module C exposing (..)

import A
import B as A
import Html

main = Html.text A.x
```

Answer (score 0):

`import Html.App as App`

Its basically importing the application from html package. These functions will help you set up an Elm program that follows the Elm Architecture, a pattern for creating great code that stays great as your project grows.

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused... There is no such import. The import there gives the `Html.App` name `Html`.

Comment: Its the elm package. I think if you go through this, you will get a better understanding. [link](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-App) and for sample implementation refer this[link](https://www.dailydrip.com/topics/elm/drips/our-first-html-application)

Comment: Well, I am asking this: the two imports in my question above seem to introduce the same name in to the program, and I do not understand how this is possible. The first line in your answer gives an import that is not the same as in the question. That is why I do not understand your answer either...

Comment: `import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)` - To start off just producing some HTML. To do this, we'll import the Html module to start: `import Html exposing (..)` This says we'd like to import everything from the Html module, which is provided by the html package we installed.

Comment: In you case you are specifying what need to be imported from the pacakge. Assuming you have everything in place and you use `beginnerProgram` - provided by elm It is an easy way of wiring a model, update, and view together to make an application. It came in the html package. We'll import it into our application: `import Html.App as App`.Finally, we'll define our main function using the beginnerProgram function exposed by Html.App

Comment: Thank you very much, I am perhaps too slow, but, again, there is no import `import Html.App as App` in the code.

Comment: You can give any for eg as you code `import Html.App as Html` main function using the beginnerProgram function exposed by Html.App: will look as below `main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = 0
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }`
The name can be anything, what you specify will become the prefix. Now if you updated as  `import Html.App as abc`
main function will look like
``main =
  abc.beginnerProgram
    { model = 0
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }``

Comment: ok, so now we have established that we import `Html.App` and give it an alias `Html`. At the same time the line above that imports a few names from the `Html` module, and one of these names is the `Html` type that is defined in this module. My question was about this fact that we import two different entities and give them the same name. I tried actually, to run this sample, and it seems that the alias for `Html.App` overwrites the type `Html` imported from the `Html` module. Thanks.

Comment: @akonsu The alias for Html.App doesn't overwrite the type Html - they live in two separate collections. If you do `view : Html msg`, it still works.